# Does Leaflet shapefile plugin work with polylines

Tags: javascript, leaflet, shapefile

Does anyone know if Calvin Metcalf's Shapefile.js plugin for Leaflet works on polyline shapefiles? It fails for me with no errors in the console, and I'm not able to find any examples on the web. Works fine with points, and, according to coworkers, polygons, but I seem to be the first of my team to try polylines.